# Single-threaded apartment - cannot instantiate ActiveX control

Tags: .net, exception, sta, single-threaded

I need to get information about applied CSS styles in HTML page. I used AxWebBrowser and iterate IHTMLDOMNode. I'm able to get all the data I need and move the code into my application. The problem is that this part is running inside of the background worker and I got exception when trying to instantiate the control.

```
AxWebBrowser browser = new AxWebBrowser();

ActiveX control '8856f961-340a-11d0-a96b-00c04fd705a2' cannot be instantiated
because the current thread is not in a single-threaded apartment.
```

Is there any way how to solve this or other option than AxWebBrowser?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

The problem you're running into is that most background thread / worker APIs will create the thread in a Multithreaded Apartment state.  The error message indicates that the control requires the thread be a Single Threaded Apartment.

You can work around this by creating a thread yourself and specifying the STA apartment state on the thread.

```
var t = new Thread(MyThreadStartMethod);
t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
t.Start();
```

Comment: Thanks, great this is working. One more questions/problem. The class I'm using is just class and the AxWebBrowser looks like it needs to be added into this.Controls(). Is there way how to fake the Controls? Or will I need to have separated Form for that?

Comment: @martin.malek There's no great way to fake that.  The best bet is to create a new form.

Comment: Hi, the code should be t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);

Comment: Confirmed Dawkins comment, I also had to change it to AppartmentState.STA.

Comment: I've met this error when I want to open a windowsfrom from my XNA-Game. I've opened the form with JaredPar's code and it works. Can I carry this code inside the windows form's code ?

Comment: Beware that this code is not enough to properly implement an STA thread, it must also pump a message loop.  Particularly WebBrowser will malfunction, it will not fire its DocumentCompleted event.  Check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21684059/17034) for an alternative.

Comment: How do you do this in the Compact Framework. (i.e. compact framework has no `[STAThread]` ability.)

Comment: I am using Task, is there any solution?

Answer (score 68):

Go ahead and add [STAThread] to the main entry of your application, this indicates the COM threading model is single-threaded apartment (STA)

example:

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new WebBrowser());
    }
}
```

Comment: doesnt work in framework 4.5 - gives invalid arguments on last line

Answer (score 4):

If you used `[STAThread]` to the main entry of your application and still get the error you may need to make a **Thread-Safe call** to the control... something like below. In my case with the same problem the following solution worked!

```
Private void YourFunc(..)
{
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate()
        {
           // Call your method YourFunc(..);
        }));
    }
    else
    {
        ///
    }
```

Comment: What should be invoked in here? The browser? In which state? In my case the browser is sitting on a dialog.

Answer (score 1):

My problem with this was that I had my Main method marked as `async`. So fixed it just by making it `static void` and adding `.wait()` to all `await`able methods inside.