# Using STA for WebBrowser Control

Tags: c#, visual-studio, browser, windows-forms-designer, sta

I am trying to add a WebBrowser to an application to be able to display a webpage, but keep getting a problem with the threading type.

Currently I am getting:

> ActiveX control '8856f961-340a-11d0-a96b-00c04fd705a2' cannot be
>   instantiated because the current thread is not in a single-threaded
>   apartment.

And I have found this question that relates to this problem: [Single-threaded apartment - cannot instantiate ActiveX control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418466/single-threaded-apartment-cannot-instantiate-activex-control)

However, I do not have a Main() method in my code and when I try the solution to that question, then I encounter an error when adding the WebBrowser to the Form controls.

---

I am using the code found here:

http://www.apress.com/9781430228530

Direct Download: http://www.apress.com/downloadable/download/sample/sample_id/1173/

And I am on Chapter 14 and inside the HorizontalExplorerBar folder.

---

Here is the code that I am using for reference:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using ProIeDev.BandObjectDemo.BandObject;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ProIeDev.BandObjectDemo.HorizontalExplorerBar
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public class HorizontalExplorerBar : BandObject.BandObject
    {
        private WebBrowser webBrowser1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton radioButton1;

        public HorizontalExplorerBar()
        {
           // var t = new Thread(InitializeComponent);
           // t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
          //  t.Start();
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public override void DefineMetadata() 
        {

            ClassId = "{B028EA5C-B226-4E4B-88C6-8842A152BC5B}";
            ProgId = "ProIeDev.BandObjectDemo.HorizontalExplorerBar";
            ObjectName = "TodoBar Horizontal";
            ObjectTitle = "TodoBar Horizontal";
            HelpText = "TodoBar Horizontal";
            Style = BandObjectTypes.HorizontalExplorerBar;

        }

        #region Form Designer

        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.radioButton1 = new System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton();
            this.webBrowser1 = new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // radioButton1
            // 
            this.radioButton1.AutoSize = true;
            this.radioButton1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(323, 34);
            this.radioButton1.Name = "radioButton1";
            this.radioButton1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(85, 17);
            this.radioButton1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.radioButton1.TabStop = true;
            this.radioButton1.Text = "radioButton1";
            this.radioButton1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // webBrowser1
            // 
            this.webBrowser1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(44, 19);
            this.webBrowser1.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(20, 20);
            this.webBrowser1.Name = "webBrowser1";
            this.webBrowser1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(250, 250);
            this.webBrowser1.TabIndex = 1;
            // 
            // HorizontalExplorerBar
            // 
            this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkBlue;
            this.Controls.Add(this.webBrowser1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.radioButton1);
            this.Name = "HorizontalExplorerBar";
            this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(456, 177);
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

        }

        #endregion Form Designer

    }
}
```