# How to write the response data into browser?

Tags: c#, asp.net, microsoft-translator

```
System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient(); 

string webData = wc.DownloadString(absuri);
```

After I downloaded the html from browser I am translating the text using Microsoft Translator. After that, I want to show it in the browser.

I need to replace the `webRequest` response data in browser, please help me here.

```
string txtToTranslate = TextBox1.Text;
string uri = "http://api.microsofttranslator.com/v2/Http.svc/Translate?text="
             + System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(txtToTranslate)
             + "&from=en&to=es";
System.Net.WebRequest translationWebRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(uri);
translationWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", headerValue);

System.Net.WebResponse response = null;
response = translationWebRequest.GetResponse();
System.IO.Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();

System.Text.Encoding encode = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
System.IO.StreamReader translatedStream = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream, encode)

System.Xml.XmlDocument xTranslation = new System.Xml.XmlDocument()
xTranslation.LoadXml(translatedStream.ReadToEnd());
string resdata = xTranslation.InnerText;

WebBrowser webBrowser = new WebBrowser();
webBrowser.DocumentStream = stream;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418466/single-threaded-apartment-cannot-instantiate-activex-control

Comment: my scenario and issue is differnt

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();   string webData = wc.DownloadString(absuri); after downloaded the html from browser than i am translating text using microsoft translator,so here i should replace the translator text in browser...how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

The `WebBrowser` control you are using now is a Windows Forms or WPF control, not an ASP.NET control, which it seems you are asking for.

If you want to return anything to the browser, you have to set the response of the current HTTP context:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(resdata /*your desired output to the client*/);
```