# ActiveX control 'guid' cannot be instantiated - Trying to make a button run a method in MVC

Tags: c#, azure-ad-b2c

I'm trying to authenticate into Azure AD B2C using the following on my mvc controller:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> AZLogin()
{
    var result = await MsalAppBuilder.BuildPublicClientApplication().AcquireTokenInteractive(Globals.Scopes).ExecuteAsync();
    return null;

}
```

However I run into this:

```
ActiveX control '8856f961-340a-11d0-a96b-00c04fd705a2' cannot be instantiated because the current thread is not in a single-threaded apartment.
```

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add [STAThread] attribute to your application entry point method or read that answers as well [Single-threaded apartment - cannot instantiate ActiveX control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418466/single-threaded-apartment-cannot-instantiate-activex-control)